# Need help calculating percentages of each categorical variable in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

I have a data frame with around 16 columns that have yes, no and neutral as the categories. At the end I want to calculate the percentage of Yes, No and Neutral. An example of the data frame is:

```
a = c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'neutral', 'no', 'yes','no','neutral','neutral')
b = c('no', 'yes','no', 'no', 'no', 'neutral', 'yes', 'neutral','neutral')
abcd = data.frame(a,b)
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in r?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the percentage for the entire dataframe as a whole we can `unlist` the data, calculate their count using `table` and convert it into percentage.

```
table(unlist(abcd))/(nrow(abcd) * ncol(abcd)) * 100

# neutral     no     yes 
# 33.333  38.889  27.778
```

---

If you want to do this for each column separately, we can use `sapply`

```
sapply(abcd, table)/nrow(abcd) * 100

#             a      b
#neutral 33.333 33.333
#no      33.333 44.444
#yes     33.333 22.222
```

---

**EDIT**

If there are certain levels missing, we can convert it to `factor` first and then use `table`

```
sapply(abcd, function(x) 
     table(factor(x, levels = c("Yes", "No", "Neutral"))))/nrow(abcd) * 100
```

Comment: When I'm trying this, on my data that has 14 columns and ~150 rows, I'm getting an error: Error in sapply(percentagesdata, table)/ncol(percentagesdata) : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: @Praneeth Ummm..this works on the sample data provided though. Maybe try, `(sapply(abcd, table)/nrow(abcd)) * 100` if this gives you the same error can you share `dput(head(abcd))` ?

Comment: I still get the same error. The output when i tried dput is:
structure(list(`Answer 2` = c("Yes", "Neutral", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Neutral"), `Answer 3` = c("No", "Neutral", "No", "No", 
"No", "No"), ..... `Answer 15` = c("Yes", "Neutral", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")).

I put in ....  but that indicates there are other 10 columns in between.

Comment: @Praneeth Can you try the updated answer in the **EDIT** part.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# For each combination: 

res <- data.frame(round(prop.table(table(abcd)) * 100, 2))

# For each var separately: 

res$total_a_cat <- ave(res$Freq, res$a, FUN = sum)

res$total_b_cat <- ave(res$Freq, res$b, FUN = sum)
```

Data:

```
abcd <-
      structure(list(
        a = structure(
          c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L,
            1L),
          .Label = c("neutral", "no", "yes"),
          class = "factor"
        ),
        b = structure(
          c(2L,
            3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L),
          .Label = c("neutral", "no",
                     "yes"),
          class = "factor"
        )
      ),
      class = "data.frame",
      row.names = c(NA,-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution that uses less code:

```
library(tidyverse)
 data%>%
   freq_table(sex)
  var cat     n n_total  percent       se   t_crit      lcl      ucl
1 sex   1 22640   38738 58.44391 0.250394 1.960025 57.95230 58.93383
2 sex   2 16098   38738 41.55609 0.250394 1.960025 41.06617 42.04770
```

This function can also make a cross-table by passing more categorical variables to it.